# How can I solve my TypeScript/ESLint/Webpack transpiling problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, eslint

I've checked other threads for more than a few days; I've found the same error online a few times, but haven't been able to replicate a posted solution. The fact that there's so many ways of writing babel/webpack configs for each different version hasn't helped much. I'm running Webpack, TS, and ESLint. The 'best case' error I've been able to get is the following. I'd really love some help! :[ Among many things, I've tried turning tsx's into jsx's and using jsx preserve instead of react.

**Terminal compiler error:**

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Milo\Desktop\Programacion\zekeapp\src\index.tsx: Unexpected token (12:2)

  10 | 
  11 | ReactDOM.render(
> 12 |   <Provider store={store}>
     |   ^
  13 |     <Router>
  14 |       <Main />
  15 |     </Router>
```

**index.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import store from './store';
import Main from './containers/Main';
import { lightTheme } from './templates/theme';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Main />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**webpack.config.tsx**

```
import * as path from 'path';

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, './src/index.tsx'),
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/scripts')
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: "ES3" (default), "ES5", "ES2015", "ES2016", "ES2017", "ES2018", "ES2019" or "ESNEXT". */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: "none", "commonjs", "amd", "system", "umd", "es2015", or "ESNext". */,
    "jsx": "preserve" /* Specify JSX code generation: "preserve", "react-native", or "react". */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "noImplicitAny": false /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied "any" type. */,
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify module resolution strategy: "node" (Node.js) or "classic" (TypeScript pre-1.6). */,
    "baseUrl": "./" /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */,
    "paths": {
      "#server/*": ["./server/*"],
      "#src/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "experimentalDecorators": true /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

Comment: Either turn that tsx into jsx, or perhaps stop using "jsx": "preserve" and make it generate "react" instead?

Comment: I've tried both of those, they throw up *exactly* the same error, only with the 'tsx' changed with a 'jsx'.

Comment: protip: [put that in your post](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app` for the build or is this a vanilla project you are setting up from scratch?

Comment: It's set up from scratch.

Comment: How is babel being configured? I'd expect to see a `.babelrc` file with [@babel/preset-react](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react) enabled. That said, my reading of the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#basic-usage) (Disclaimer: I don't use TypeScript myself) makes me think that `"jsx":"react"` should eliminate the need for Babel's JSX parsing altogether - I'm surprised to hear that's not working.

Comment: Could you [edit] you're question to include the command you're running to generate that output? If you're running `$ [yarn|npx] webpack`, that might explain why `"jsx":"react"` isn't working - because you're not running it through TypeScript!

Answer (score 7):

I got an example project working by following the official [React & Webpack](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) documentation.

Make these changes:

1. Rename `webpack.config.tsx` to `webpack.config.js` (it's run by node not TypeScript)
2. Install `ts-loader` to transpile the .ts/.tsx files: `npm install --save-dev ts-loader`
3. Edit `webpack.config.js` and configure ts-loader

This example includes `babel-loader` as well.

Note the `exclude: /node_modules/,` and `configFile: path.resolve('./tsconfig.json'),` lines, they are important and required to work properly (see troubleshooting section below for details)

```
    // webpack.config.js
    {
        //...
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'babel-loader',
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'ts-loader',
                            options: {
                                configFile: path.resolve('./tsconfig.json'),
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

4. Edit `tsconfig.json` and add these settings:

```
    // tsconfig.json
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            //...

            // Can use to "react" if you aren't using `babel-loader` and `@babel/preset-react` to handle jsx
            "jsx": "react" /* Specify JSX code generation: "preserve", "react-native", or "react". */,

            // Include these so the `react` imports work nicely:
            "esModuleInterop": true,
            "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
        }
    }
```

5. You should hopefully be able to build the project at this point: `npx webpack`

```
    $ npx webpack
    Hash: 184cde71516bcbc08144
    Version: webpack 4.41.5
    Time: 2558ms
    Built at: 01/13/2020 2:34:08 PM
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  128 KiB       0  [emitted]  main
    Entrypoint main = bundle.js
    [2] ./src/index.tsx 498 bytes {0} [built]
    [8] ./src/Main.tsx 385 bytes {0} [built]
        + 7 hidden modules
```

---

## 2. Example files

Here are the file contents for my test project:

**package.json**

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
        "typescript": "^3.7.4",
        "webpack": "^4.41.5",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^16.9.17",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
        "react": "^16.12.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2018" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: "ES3" (default), "ES5", "ES2015", "ES2016", "ES2017", "ES2018", "ES2019" or "ESNEXT". */,
        "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: "none", "commonjs", "amd", "system", "umd", "es2015", or "ESNext". */,
        "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
        "noImplicitAny": false /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied "any" type. */,
        "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify module resolution strategy: "node" (Node.js) or "classic" (TypeScript pre-1.6). */,
        "baseUrl": "./" /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */,
        "experimentalDecorators": true /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
        "jsx": "react" /* Specify JSX code generation: "preserve", "react-native", or "react". */,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    }
}
```

**webpack.config.json**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, './src/index.tsx'),
    mode: 'production',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/scripts')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            configFile: path.resolve('./tsconfig.json'),
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**src/index.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Main from './Main';

ReactDOM.render( <Main />, document.getElementById('root') );
```

**src/Main.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default function Main(){
    return (<h1>This is Main</h1>);
}
```

---

## 3. Troubleshooting

I ran into these issues getting this set up - here are the solutions I found.

**Error:** You get an error like: `The 'files' list in config file 'tsconfig.json' is empty.`

e.g.

```
ERROR in [tsl] ERROR
  TS18002: The 'files' list in config file 'tsconfig.json' is empty.

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: error while parsing tsconfig.json
```

**Solution:** resolve the full `tsconfig.json` path

```
// webpack.config.js
{
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    options: {
        // configFile: './tsconfig.json', // !! WRONG
        configFile: path.resolve('./tsconfig.json'),    // CORRECT
    },
}
```

---

**Error:** You get an error like: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '...' in 'path-to-project/node_modules/react'`

e.g.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Main' in 'C:\webpack-typescript\node_modules\react'
@ ./node_modules/react/index.js 15:31-48
@ ./src/index.tsx
```

**Solution:** Make sure you are excluding `node_modules` from the `ts-loader` rule.

```
// webpack.config.js
{
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/, // <--- make sure this is here!
                // ...
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay it *almost* works. I didn't run into any of those errors; but I've ran into a parsing error from webpack when it's being compiled. It says 'unexpected token '<' '; from what I've seen it seems to be a problem with the babel configuration, and I'd need to set it to preset es2015; but it sometimes doesn't work, and sometimes (when making a fresh install) it's straight up not **found**, meaning the syntax doesn't seem to be wrong in the config's declaration, it's just not found.

Comment: That sounds like babel is failing on the preserved jsx syntax being passed through to it. Have you configured babel to use `@babel/preset-react`?

Comment: Yeah, I have @babel react, env, and typescript. I'm not to sure what it was, I'll check again in a few days. I asked an ex-teacher for a config (which honestly looks 100% the same,) and it works, so I'm sticking to that. I've spent about 4 days trying to config this.